# Como seleccionar fila con un click, guardar su posición, administrar eventos

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una tabla *HTML* y deseo seleccionar una fila con un **click** y **guardar la posición de esa fila** para realizar operaciones diversas.

Para ello he hecho lo siguiente:

A cada fila de la tabla le he puesto `addEventListener('click', func())`;

```javascript
// función que permite seleccionar cada una de las filas 
function rowSelector() {
  table.style.background = 'rgba(16, 175, 114, 0.5)';
  const row = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
  row.forEach(r => {
    // estilo hover para efecto de selección 
    r.classList.add('tr-hover');
    // aplicando evento click a todas las filas de la tabla
    r.addEventListener('click', () => {
      // envía el índice de la fila por consola 
      console.log(r.rowIndex);
    });
  });
  tr_action_flag = true;
  btn_done.disabled = false;
}
```

Básicamente esta función recoge el índice de la fila seleccionada y lo muestra por consola, esto funciona bien.

El problema esta en la administración de los eventos, es decir, el momento en que el evento debe detenerse o removerse ya que una vez mostrado el índice de la fila en la consola, el evento **click** sigue activo. Deseo removerlo al presionar un botón **-aceptar-**

```javascript
// función del botón que deberá descartar los eventos click de las filas en la tabla 
btn_done.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (tr_action_flag) {
    const tr = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
    for (let i = 0, j = tr.length; i < j; i++) {
      tr[i].classList.remove('tr-hover');
      tr[i].removeEventListener('click', rowI);
    }
  }
  btn_done.disabled = true;
});
```

Para remover los eventos he intentado con `removeEventListener('click', rowI)`, con los mismos parámetros que la  función a remover. Pero para ello se debe declarar la función que el **addEventListener()** recibe, fuera de la función **rowSelector()**, y no como una función anónima como se muestra en la primera muestra de código más arriba.

```javascript
// misma función pero sin declaración de función anónima
function rowSelector() {
  table.style.background = 'rgba(16, 175, 114, 0.5)';
  const row = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
  row.forEach(r => {
    // estilo hover para efecto de selección 
    r.classList.add('tr-hover');
    // aplicando evento click a todas las filas de la tabla, llamando a función rowI();
    r.addEventListener('click', rowI(r.rowIndex));
  });
  tr_action_flag = true;
  btn_done.disabled = false;
}

// declaración externa
function rowI(index) {
  console.log('cell selected ' + index);
}
```

Al declararla y pasarle los parámetros correspondientes, que en este caso es el índice de la fila seleccionada, esta muestra por consola todas las filas de la tabla lo cual no deseo

Objetivos

- Mostrar el índice de la fila
- Remover evento **click** una vez presionado un botón

***Observaciones:*** Mostrarlo por consola es solo una forma rápida de visualizarlo, el objetivo más adelante será enviarlo a métodos como **removeCell**, el cual necesita el índice de la fila en donde se encuentra la celda.

HTML

```
<table id="table" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Alberto Gonzales</td>
    <td>Juna lopes</td>
    <td>Jhon Sat</td>
    <td>48</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Leonidas Morales</td>
    <td>Ernest Carralde</td>
    <td>125</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Diana rodrigues</td>
    <td>Carlos Fernandez</td>
    <td>Alberto Fernandez</td>
    <td>62</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Lilian Peña</td>
    <td>Carlos Gutierres</td>
    <td>123</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No se porque te complicas tanto. Tal como me parece que quieres que funcione todo eso te sugiero que uses simples checkboxes en cada fila para seleccionar o deseleccionar las filas que desees y luego te será más facil, tanto visualmente como a nivel de código, realizar acciones sobre ellos.

Comment: Gracias por editar el enunciado, pase por alto los detalles.
Entiendo, parece una buna idea. Pero supongamos que quiero eliminar solo una celda o varias que he seleccionado con el mouse. ¿Cómo lo haría ?

Comment: Seria una función que repasa un array con todos los checkboxes y comprueba su atributo checked, y los que esten marcados los elimina. Y para llamar a la función podria ser con el atributo onclick="" o bien con un addEventListener sobre el elemento del botón

Comment: Entiendo, gracias.